# changing squirrelmail folder tree display options do not alter appearance in user interface

Tags: squirrelmail

```
FreeBSD-11.1 and CentOS-6.9
Apache-2.4 and Apache-2.2
SquirrelMail-1.4.23 and SquirrelMail-1.4.22
```

I have discovered that I cannot change the format of the folder tree display in the left hand frame of the SM user interface.  On our existing Centos-6.9/Apache-2.2/SquirrelMail-1.4.22 my folder display option is set to Indented, and that is how it appears.  However, if I change the option to Long or Delimited, Submit the change and reload the page the folder tree display does not change from Indented.

Similarly, on our new SM install on FreeBSD-11.1/Apache-2.4/SM-1.4.23 my selected folder display option is Indented but the folder tree displays as Delimited and no toggling of settings in the Folder Preferences Options to Delimited, Long or back to Indented produces any visible change.

In both cases changing the option is sticky, in that the selected option persists.  It just has no effect on the display.

I have asked about this twice on the SM users list these past two days and have received no reply.

Has anyone else encountered this problem?  Are there any ideas as to what is causing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was answered by a user on the cyrus-imap mailing list.  This issue is caused by specifying a delimiter in *Squirrelmails's* (SM) ***IMAP*** server settings configuration which differs from that specified in the `imapd.conf` file of the ***IMAP*** service in question.

Changing the value of the setting from a specific character, in our case **`.`** to **`detect`** resolved the issue.

```
SquirrelMail Configuration : Read: config.php
Config version 1.4.0; SquirrelMail version 1.4.23 [SVN]
---------------------------------------------------------
Server Settings

. . .

IMAP Settings
--------------
. . .
5.  IMAP Port              : 993
6.  Authentication type    : login
7.  Secure IMAP (TLS)      : TLS
8.  Server software        : cyrus
9.  Delimiter              : detect
```